# How to copy content of one file to another in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>

void main() {
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
char a;

fp1 = fopen("input.txt", "r");
if (fp1 == NULL) {
  puts("cannot open this file");
  exit(0);
}

fp2 = fopen("output.txt", "w");
if (fp2 == NULL) {
  puts("Not able to open this file");
  fclose(fp1);
  exit(0);
}

do {
  a = fgetc(fp1);
  fputc(a, fp2);
} while (a != EOF);

fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);
getch();
}
```

I create the file input.txt and output.txt and after I run program I didn't see that text was copied. (I create .txt file from cmd and directly from notepad also but both didn't work)

Comment: Have you referenced this which is performing a very similar operation? http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/write-a-program-to-copy-the-contents-of-one-file-into-another-using-fputc.html

Comment: Change void main(){} to **int main(void){}**

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the following changes.

**Suggestion 1**

Use

```
int a;
```

instead of

```
char a;
```

Depending on whether type of `char` is signed or unsigned on your platform,

```
a = fgetc(fp1);
```

might be problem if `a` is of type `char` since `fgetc` returns an `int` .

**Suggestion 2**

The `do-while` loop is flawed. You will end up calling `fputc(a, fp2)` even for `a = EOF` with your current setup. Change it to:

```
while ( (a = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF )
{
   fputc(a, fp2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works,but it adds garbage value to output.txt.so you have to change the `do-while` loop to a `while` loop to resolve this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>

void main() {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    int a;

    fp1 = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
      puts("cannot open this file");
      exit(0);
    }

    fp2 = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
      puts("Not able to open this file");
      fclose(fp1);
      exit(0);
    }
    while( (a = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF )
    {
      fputc(a, fp2);
    }

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

you can also use `getc` and `putc` instead of `fgetc` and `fputc`

Comment: How can he do it with `getc` and `putc`? They work with `stdin` and `stdout`, not files opened by the program.

Comment: EOF is a (signed) integer and so it depends on the default signedness of `char` whether or not it can equal your variable `a`. Minor: if the "text file" contains a byte `0xFF` - perhaps as part of a Unicode BOM or an UTF8 sequence - copying will stop prematurely.

Comment: @Barmar what are you talking about? `getc` takes `FILE* ` and `putc` takes `int` and `FILE*`.I also tested the code with them,and it works.I agree that a should be declared as `int` but it still works!

Comment: "It works" because of (I already said so) the default signedness of `char` on your system. (Barmar may have confused `getc` and `fgetc` with [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar); I know I did, and still do, until corrected by my compiler.)

Comment: @machine_1 Yes, I was confusing it with `getchar`.

Answer (score 0):

This function copy a content of a first file to a second file. If the second file exists - will to override it, otherwise - will to create it and to write the content of the first file to it. The key for this function is the function **fputc()** (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fputc/).

---

**A solution**

```
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * Copy content from one file to other file.
 */
int
copy_file(char path_to_read_file[], char path_to_write_file[])
{
    char chr;
    FILE *stream_for_write, *stream_for_read;

    if ((stream_for_write = fopen(path_to_write_file, "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", "Impossible to create a file", path_to_write_file);
        return -1;
    }

    if ((stream_for_read = fopen(path_to_read_file, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", "Impossible to read a file", path_to_read_file);
        return -1;
    }

    while ((chr = fgetc(stream_for_read)) != EOF)
        fputc(chr, stream_for_write);

    fclose(stream_for_write);
    fclose(stream_for_read);

    return 0;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    copy_file("file1", "file2");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(chr = fgetc(stream_for_read)) != EOF`. EOF is actually a `-1`, so if chr is signed (as usually is), then you may get some byte from file which is treated as -1 and therefore EOF.